# Import CSV to google sheets with separate headers by client

Tags: google-sheets, import, postman

I have downloaded the data to csv via Postman.
The problem is that I don't have a classic structure:

```
id;name;country
1;Paul;USA
2;John;Germany
```

but structure like this

```
id:1;
name:Paul;
country:USA;
id:2;
name:John;
Country:Germany
```

Do I still need to edit the data in Postman, or is there any way to import it directly in google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

example of recombination:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(PROPER(SPLIT(A1:A; ":;"))); 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1");;9^9)); " ")); 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col1"))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Et61cnsQpWRJmze7LbcRpwX34jHV34Pte7v3fyBvPxc/edit#gid=1421149923)